# Find products adds to cart in specific page in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

In Universal Google Analytics (with enhanced ecommerce installed), how can I know witch products were added to cart in a specific page?

I've tried to create a custom report with "Page", "Product SKU" and the metric "Quantity added to cart". In this report, the URL in page dimension doesn't show the specific page, but the generic version of the page. Like /category.aspx instead of /clothes/shirts/white-shirts.aspx.

Any suggestions about how to grab the information I need?

Thanks.
Lopes

Answer (score 0):

If you have tracked the add to cart as an event (i.e. with specific category, action or label), you can find the pages where that event was triggered.

Comment: Hi.
Unfortunately I have not created those events.
It's weird to me that an enhaced ecommerce installation doesn't allow me to have this kind of simple granularity. :)

Comment: You can always create them. I mean that you can send the information of the enhanced ecommerce accompanied each by an event, in this way for each interaction you also have an event with the nomenclature that you decide.